# typescript kendo-ui call method from string

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, typescript, transpiler

i'm using dropdrownlist within grid from kendo-ui (html) with typescript

problem is i have to call a function in string

```
export class ClassName extends BaseController {

    public configureGrid()
        {

           .... //other codes

              columnView.template =  "#= methodToBeCalled(columnValue) #";
        }
    }

    public methodToBeCalled(...params:any[])
            {
                return "something";
            }
```

how should i call 'methodToBeCalled' from typescript which is defined in string.
i tried these combinations, and non of them worked

```
      columnView.template =  "#= methodToBeCalled(columnValue) #";
      columnView.template =  "#= this.methodToBeCalled(columnValue) #";
      columnView.template =  "#= _this.methodToBeCalled(columnValue) #";
      columnView.template =  "#= ClassName.methodToBeCalled(columnValue) #";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try compiling the template manually and then using `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
columnView.template = kendo.template("#=methodToBeCalled(columnValue)#").bind(this);
```